# How to make a sidewalk on blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, edges, shortcut, loop

I would like to make a sidewalk for a 3D project but I can't find how to do it, I looked for tutorials, but nothing tells me how to make the lines or the cut lines on the edge of the sidewalk

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could just project an image texture on a volume?

Comment: yes but I would have preferred to do it myself for better quality :/

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried so far? I'm not sure about the difficulty you've met with the modeling

Comment: why don't you just array cubes with a small margin (as this sidewalks are in reality too)?

Comment: Yes I would say Array + Subdivision Surface + Displacement modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one block, bevel the angles:

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier, a *Subdivision Surface* to add virtual topology, and a *Displacement* modifier with a *Cloud* texture in order to create a bit of random bumps on the surface:

[image]

If you can't use a *Subdivision Surface* and a *Displacement* modifier because it's too high in polygon, fake the bumps in your material with a *Bump* node.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you very much !